# Calculating average dataframe filtered by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe

```
    Unnamed: 0  Datetime    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    Ball PossessionMatch_H  Ball PossessionMatch_A
0   0   2021-05-24 02:30:00 U. De Chile Everton                         68      32
1   1   2021-05-23 21:00:00 Huachipato  Colo Colo                       48      52
2   2   2021-05-23 18:30:00 Melipilla   Antofagasta                     47      53
3   3   2021-05-23 02:30:00 U. Espanola U. Catolica                     37      63
4   4   2021-05-23 00:00:00 S. Wanderers    O'Higgins                   29      71
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
57  57  2021-03-28 15:45:00 Palestino   Antofagasta                     58      42
58  58  2021-03-28 01:00:00 U. Espanola S. Wanderers                    50      50
59  59  2021-03-27 22:30:00 Colo Colo   Union La Calera                 58      42
60  60  2021-03-27 20:00:00 Everton O'Higgins                           54      46
61  61  2021-03-27 15:00:00 Curico Unido    Melipilla                   41      59
```

I want to split it in multiple dataframes and apply two criteria in "HomeTeam" and "AwayTeam", then calculate the average of Ball Possession and put it in a new column "Ball PossessionMatch_H/MP" if the team is in "HomeTeam" and "Ball PossessionMatch_A/MP" if the team is in "AwayTeam"

Code:

```
teams = pd.unique(df[['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']].values.ravel('K'))
df_list3 = []
for team in teams:
    if team in df['HomeTeam']:
        current_df = df[(df.HomeTeam == team) | (df.AwayTeam == team)].copy()
        current_df["Ball PossessionMatch_H/MP"] = current_df.apply(
            lambda x: (
                current_df[(current_df.HomeTeam == team)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "Ball PossessionMatch_H"].sum()
                + current_df[(current_df.AwayTeam == team)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "Ball PossessionMatch_A"].sum()
            )
            / (
                current_df[(current_df.HomeTeam == team)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "Ball PossessionMatch_H"].size
                + current_df[(current_df.AwayTeam == team)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "Ball PossessionMatch_A"].size
            ),
            axis=1,
        )
    else:
        current_df = df[(df.HomeTeam == team) | (df.AwayTeam == team)].copy()
        current_df["Ball PossessionMatch_A/MP"] = current_df.apply(
            lambda x: (
                current_df[(current_df.HomeTeam == team)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "Ball PossessionMatch_H"].sum()
                + current_df[(current_df.AwayTeam == team)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "Ball PossessionMatch_A"].sum()
            )
            / (
                current_df[(current_df.HomeTeam == team)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "Ball PossessionMatch_H"].size
                + current_df[(current_df.AwayTeam == team)].loc[x.name + 1 :, "Ball PossessionMatch_A"].size
            ),
            axis=1,
        )
        df_list3.append(current_df)

df = pd.concat(df_list3)
print(df)
```

It does not consider the `if` and create only "Ball PossessionMatch_A/MP" column with calculated values and duplicates the rows, I would `append` the results to the original dataframe.

Expected Result:

```
    Unnamed: 0  Datetime    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    Ball PossessionMatch_H  Ball PossessionMatch_A  Ball PossessionMatch_H/MP   Ball PossessionMatch_A/MP
0   0   2021-05-24 02:30:00 U. De Chile Everton               68           32         50.33      43.5
```

Comment: Maybe have a look into the `groupby` method from pandas.DataFrame. e.g. df.groupby('HomeTeam')['Ball PossessionMatch_H'].mean()

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
hometeam_count = df.groupby("HomeTeam")["Ball PossessionMatch_H"].count()
hometeam_sum = df.groupby("HomeTeam")["Ball PossessionMatch_H"].sum()
awayteam_count = df.groupby("AwayTeam")["Ball PossessionMatch_A"].count()
awayteam_sum = df.groupby("AwayTeam")["Ball PossessionMatch_A"].sum()

df["Ball PossessionMatch_H/MP"] = df["HomeTeam"].apply(lambda x: ((hometeam_sum.loc[x] if x in hometeam_sum.index else 0) + (awayteam_sum.loc[x] if x in awayteam_sum.index else 0)) / ((hometeam_count.loc[x] if x in hometeam_count.index else 0)  + (awayteam_count.loc[x] if x in awayteam_count.index else 0)))
df["Ball PossessionMatch_A/MP"] = df["AwayTeam"].apply(lambda x: ((hometeam_sum.loc[x] if x in hometeam_sum.index else 0) + (awayteam_sum.loc[x] if x in awayteam_sum.index else 0)) / ((hometeam_count.loc[x] if x in hometeam_count.index else 0)  + (awayteam_count.loc[x] if x in awayteam_count.index else 0)))
```

The code above utilises the `groupby` function to calculate the `sum` and the `count` for each team and for both `Ball PossessionMatch_A` and `Ball PossessionMatch_H` separately.
The second part of the code basically looking up (`loc`) the corresponding `sum` and `count` values for each `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` respectively, and perform the average calculation as intended.

As you can tell, the code for both `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` are pretty much identical which also be cleaned up so that we [Dont' repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). I presented as such purely for readability purpose.

Although this does not solve the problem (as to why the values are not filled in the columns that you have created), I am providing an alternative solution to the question, which I think is more intuitive and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The code seems work well. There is only one issue, it calculates from the current row instead should calculates from one row down

Comment: What do you mean with "current row" and "one row down"?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Just helping you to progress in some direction, not providing a copy/paste solution.

I edited a bit your dataframe for demonstration purposes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     "Datetime": [pd.Timestamp(x) for x in ["2021-05-24 02:30:00", "2021-05-23 21:00:00", 
                                            "2021-05-23 18:30:00", "2021-05-23 02:30:00", 
                                            "2021-05-23 00:00:00"]],
     "HomeTeam": ["Huachipato", "Huachipato", "Huachipato", "U. Espanola", "U. Espanola"],
     "AwayTeam": ["Everton", "Colo Colo", "Antofagasta", "Everton",  "Colo Colo"],
     "Ball PossessionMatch_A": [68, 48, 47, 37, 29],
    }     
)


print(df.groupby("HomeTeam")["Ball PossessionMatch_A"].mean())
```

The output is:

```
HomeTeam
Huachipato     54.333333
U. Espanola    33.000000
Name: Ball PossessionMatch_A, dtype: float64
```

Now if you need to filter on some other information, say for a given "AwayTeam" such as "Everton", you could:

```
print(df[df["AwayTeam"].eq("Everton")].groupby("HomeTeam")["Ball PossessionMatch_A"].mean())
```

and then you would get:

```
HomeTeam
Huachipato     68
U. Espanola    37
Name: Ball PossessionMatch_A, dtype: int64
```